# Derby DB - the list of characters to escape when saving String as CLOB in Java

Tags: java, database, escaping, derby

Because of commercial license issues I switched from MySQL to Derby DB. So now I have to escape special characters like single quotation marks and so on - and it is quite different from MySQL. So what I'm doing before storing Strings as CLOB data to Derby DB:

```
public static String escapeSQL(String text) {
        return text
                .replace("\'", "\''");
                //And the rest of MUST escape characters
    }
```

So my question is - how this list should be completed? What are all the the characters which must be escaped?

Comment: What makes you think there are characters that must be escaped?

Comment: Because here you will get syntax error: `st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO myTable ("someColumn1, someColumn2") VALUES ('ok', 'this will cause'syntax error')");`

Comment: Use a `PreparedStatement` instead. Not only can you stop worrying about escaping special characters but your application will also be less vulnerable to SQL injection (you already should have done that in MySQL btw)

Answer (score 1):

This is about parsing the string literals in your program, and not about the column type you use. Best way to avoid such issues is to use a prepared statement.